# Include @ in string name xml file

Tags: android, xml

For example I want to make a String array in my xml resource file and I need to have the strings start with an @ then I am going to load these strings into an array adapter for later use.

```
 <string-array name="options">
    <item>Off</item>
    <item>@5 minutes</item>
    <item>@10 minutes</item>
    <item>@15 minutes</item>
    <item>@20 minutes</item>
</string-array>
```

The error I am getting is no resource type specified. So is there a way that I can make this work with some type of escape sequence that I am unaware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its easy. Escape it by using \@

```
  <item>\@5 minutes</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use html value for @ symbol in string resources. For example:

```
<item>&#64;5 minutes</item>
```